# Raising explicit implemented event

Tags: c#

Consider the following constellation.

```
public delegate void BarHandler(Foo sender, FooEventArgs<Object> args);
public delegate void BarHandler<T>(Foo<T> sender, FooEventArgs<T> args);

public interface Foo
{
    Object Value
    { get; }

    event BarHandler BarEvent;

    void Update();
}

public interface Foo<T> : Foo
{
    new T Value
    { get; }

    new event BarHandler<T> BarEvent;
}

public class Baz<T> : Foo<T>
{
    Object Foo.Value
    { get { return Value; } }

    public T Value
    { get; set; }

    private BarHandler handler;

    event BarHandler Foo.BarEvent
    {
        add{ handler += value; }
        remove{ handler -= value; }
    }

    public event BarHandler<T> BarEvent;

    public void Update()
    {
        BarEvent(this, new FooEventArgs<T>());
        (this as Foo).BarEvent(this, new FooEventArgs<Object>());
    }
}
```

I have a Interface and a Generic Interface which extends the first Interface and a class that extends the generic Interface. The generic interface hides the not generic one, via the new keyword.
The Update method should raise both, the not-generic and the generic one. And that is the problem I am dealing with at the moment.
The resulting error is:

```
The event BarEvent can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= when used outside of Foo.
```

But I am in Foo, or do I miss something?

So, what I want is, regardless on which event the client has been registerd, it should be notified. I also should mention, that both, add and remove must work, so there is no option with delegates or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the private `handler` variable, this should do the trick.

```
public void Update()
{
    BarEvent(this, new FooEventArgs<T>());
    handler(this, new FooEventArgs<Object>());
}
```

It would probably also be a good idea to check `BarEvent` and `handler` for `null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works fine. And of course I do the null check, but it was nothing that would help in this example, so I left it out.